# Connect Yamaha MDBT01 Wireless Bluetooth MIDI Adapter to macOS Mojave

Tags: bluetooth, mojave, midi

I just bought a Yamaha MDBT01 Wireless Bluetooth MIDI Adapter.

I plug it into my keyboard. It powers on, there is a red light showing on the MIDI adapter, and it briefly flashes green at regular intervals.

I read [this guide from Yamaha](https://www.yamahasynth.com/yamaha-synth-rss/md-ud-bt01-for-mac-os) for connecting to macOS. It says to launch Audio MIDI Studio.app and then navigate to Window > Show MIDI Studio.

Then it says to click the bluetooth button:

[image]

Unfortunately I can't find this button in mine, so I don't know how I am meant to add the MIDI Adapter as an input.

[image]

Comment: I have screenshots but can't upload them to stackexchange

Comment: You should be able to upload screenshots while editing your post. If, for whatever reason, this doesn't work for you, make them accessible through Dropbox/imgur/iCloud/whatever and add the links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

The bluetooth button's in the tool bar. Add it from the window that pops up after clicking that.

Comment: The Bluetooth button is in the Toolbar not the Title Bar.

Answer (score 2):

MD-BT01 doesn't work with Mojave. Ask me how I know…

Anyway, the problem seems to be with the OS 10.14 Audio MIDI Setup.app. I copied Audio MIDI Setup.app from Utilities in a backup HD I happened to have of OS 10.12 Sierra, pasted it to the Desktop of 10.14.4 and launched it.

And hey, presto! – as soon as I switched on my Roland AX-1 keytar with MDBT01 connected, the Bluetooth icon appeared in the MIDI window. After that I just followed the instructions in the Yamaha guide you refered to and started playing in Live 10. Yay!

So, to the OP: you just need to get hold of Audio MIDI Setup.app from Sierra (or possibly earlier).

Good luck!